How to use Google keybord on ultra power saving mode
How i use Google keyboard in ultra power saving mode

Welcome to [Android.SE] Stack Exchange. Since you mentioned "Ultra Power Saving Mode", I assumed you have a Samsung device? Could you [edit] and mention the Android version, just in case it's relevant?
